# Web Application that requires "servlet-3.0" cannot be added to Websphere Liberty Server, version 8.5.6 or v9 Beta

Tags: web-applications, server, servlet-3.0, websphere-liberty

I am trying to connect a web application (downloaded from Github and imported into an Eclipse project) to a Websphere Liberty Server.

I cannot add the application to the Liberty server because the application requires a `servlet-3.0` feature, which is unsupported in the new and available releases.

How do I get these features on this version of the Websphere Liberty server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the optional step #3 on the Liberty download site has the information you need.

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/

"The installUtility (located in the wlp/bin folder) can be used to install additional features from the Liberty Repository such as adminCenter-1.0, **servlet-3.0**, collectiveController-1.0, ndControllerBundle (including adminCenter-1.0 and collectiveController-1.0), e.g.

bin/installUtility install adminCenter-1.0

You can also install all features required by a configured server using:

bin/installUtility install "

Hope it helps!