# Eclipse Mars integration with WAS Liberty server 8.5.5.6 does not recognize some Java EE 6 installed features

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, eclipse-wtp

I recently installed WAS Dev tools in Eclipse Mars from this site (https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/). I'm using the latest version of Websphere Liberty Profile (WAS Liberty with Java EE 7 Full Platform) from IBM's site.

Since my app is Java EE 6 compliant, I needed to install several features that were not shipped within the application server, such as jaxrs-1.1, cdi-1.0 etc.

I used the install utility that was mentioned in several other questions here in Stack Overflow ([Web Application that requires "servlet-3.0" cannot be added to Websphere Liberty Server, version 8.5.6 or v9 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616748/web-application-that-requires-servlet-3-0-cannot-be-added-to-websphere-liberty)).

Everything was working just fine until I had to actually deploy my app into the container. I tried to add it using the Eclipse Integration but it was refused with this message:

*Project facet Context and dependency injection (CDI) version 1.0 is not supported.*

But it **IS**!

When I copy the war file to the apps directory and add my application manually to server.xml, it works fine.

I realized later that several features have a warning message:

*The feature **xxx** is not recognized.*

These features are:

```
<feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
<feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
<feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
<feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
<feature>jsf-2.0</feature>
```

Curiously, some features that were installed the same way (jaxrs-1.1, servlet-3.0 ...) were recognized by the validation tool.

I can continue working this way, copying the WAR file to the apps directory every time I need to deploy, but this is very annoying.

Is there a way to shut down the validation tool or add these installed features manually to a config file?

Thanks a lot for your help. If you need more information, just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the tools don't realize the runtime under it has changed. The way to fix this is a little hidden, but you can fix it using the following steps:

1. From the Servers view select the server, right click and select Open
2. When opened Click Runtime Environment.
3. Click Advanced Options in the wizard.
4. Click the Refresh button. There is a label left and to the bottom that says "Last cache update" when that timestamp has changed click OK, then Finish.

WDT should now understand the features exist in the runtime and the problems you have been experiencing will go away.

Answer (score 3):

If you have downloaded version `WAS Liberty V8.5.5.6 with Java EE 7 Full Platform` then it doesn't contain Java EE 6 features.

Either install Java EE 6 features using:

```
installUtility install webProfile-6.0
```

or donwload full runtime in jar file - `WAS Liberty V8.5.5.6 Runtime`

After feature installation refresh server in the Servers view (double click server, then click `Runtime Environment > Advanced options > Refresh`)

Comment: This is also correct, but I had already found out about installUtility as you can see from my question. The refresh part was the answer I was searching for.